# Java Streams - Turn Stream into Stream of Lists

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stream of InputStreams that are all being reduced into a single InputStream with a reduce function.

It looks like this:

```
InputStream pdfReportStream = dynamoDBItems.parallelStream()
        .map(dynamoDBItem -> new ChonkRequest(dynamoDBItem.getString("s3_key"),
                dynamoDBItem.getString("s3_bucket"), dynamoDBItem.getInt("SK")))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(ChonkRequest::getIndex))
        .map(storageService::getChonk) // Stream<InputStream>
        .reduce(null, pdfService::mergePdf);
```

I have been tweaking this for about a day now. Originally I just collected the list of input lists and passed them into the merge method and it merged them all together very quickly. The problem was that with too many InputStreams it failed.

So I switched to use reduce and add one at a time. This works for larger numbers but it is slower overall and will eventually lead to a timeout on very large number of InputStreams.

What I would like to do is use a combination of both previous approaches and pass in lists of InputStreams with a max size into the mergePDF method, and have it keep performing reduce on them, outputting an InputStream everytime.

So the pseudocode would be like...

```
InputStream pdfReportStream = dynamoDBItems.parallelStream()
        .map(dynamoDBItem -> new ChonkRequest(dynamoDBItem.getString("s3_key"),
                dynamoDBItem.getString("s3_bucket"), dynamoDBItem.getInt("SK")))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(ChonkRequest::getIndex))
        .map(storageService::getChonk) // Stream<InputStream>
        .convert_individual_elements_to_lists_of_elements
        .reduce(null, pdfService::mergePdf);
```

I'm aware that the reduce method would need a converter if it's subtotal is an InputStream but the elements being added are lists of InputStreams. Not sure the best overall approach here.

Comment: what is the type of `dynamoDBItems`?

Comment: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document

Comment: so that's a list of document?

Comment: yeah, but those are just for references to get the s3 objects, and take those into the merge method as InputStreams.

Comment: `reduce` already process your streams one at a time.

Comment: right, I'm hoping to process them... for example, 50 at a time, passing into the reduce a list of the InputStreams for each reduce action.

Comment: Maybe a collect would be more appropriate. A collect takes a mutable accumulator, so you could init a single output stream, and merge items in it one by one. But I am not sure about what costs the most  time in your program. Can you add details about th pdfService::merge ? Does it open inputstream/outputstream each time ?

Comment: It takes in 2 InputStreams and outputs 1 InputStream, it could be modified to take in 1 inputstream(subtotal) and 1 list of inputstream(elements to be added to subtotal) and could then output that new inputstream.

Comment: I think you would really benefit from a sequential collect operation that append all elements in the same target. Because reducing two by two (or even 50 per 50) means you will merge bigger docs at each reduction step. Reducing is well suited when the merge operation produces an output of the same (or lesser) complexity. Collect is *really* the operation optimized for aggregation.

Comment: Would this be using a "Custom Collector"? I'm not too familiar with this Sequential Collect Operation?

Comment: It would help if you would provide more information.   What do each of the method references return?   What are the contents of the final result stream as you have shown it?  Why can't you flatten the streams into a final result stream (which should also be the List type).